# Segmentation fault while copying char * to Char *[ ] array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to copy `char *` element to `char *[]` array . I am taking each `token` values and copying to another array . Here i am using `strcpy` function , This is the `C` code i have written :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char input[20];
    char *output[20];
    char *token = NULL;
    int count = 0,i=0;
    printf("Enter the input string\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    token = strtok(input,",");
    while(NULL != token)
    {
        strcpy(*(output+i),token);
        i++;
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault on `strcpy(*(output+i),token);` this line . What exactly i am missing here ? Anybody explain a little bit would be more helpful to understand .

Comment: You have defined `output` as an array of pointers

Comment: Don't copy to `output[i]`, ***assign*** to it instead: `output[i] = token;`

Comment: ... and make sure tokenisation does not result in more then 20 tokens.

Comment: any explanation ? what will happen when i copy with strcpy ?

Comment: What does e.g. `output[0]` point to? It's *uninitialized*, and therefore *indeterminate*. It will point to some seemingly random location. What happens when you copy some data to that location? [*Undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Please consider reading the answers to the question, your question had been close for as being a duplicate question to.